# Can I find a general solution for this modified logistic ODE?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I was looking at the logistic equation : $$ \frac {dy}{dt} = r \cdot y(t)\cdot (1-\frac{y(t)}{K}) $$
For which I can quite easily find the general solution, but I was wondering how to solve this differential equation when adding a simple term at the end: 
$$ \frac {dy}{dt} = r \cdot y(t)\cdot (1-\frac{y(t)}{K}) - s \cdot y(t) $$

Can I find a general solution for this modified logistic ODE ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can do the same. Factorise the $y(t)$ and form partial fractions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Observe that the equation

$\dfrac {dy}{dt} = r \cdot y(t)\cdot \left (1-\dfrac{y(t)}{K} \right) - s \cdot y(t) \tag 1$

may be re-written as

$\dfrac {dy}{dt} = r \cdot y(t)\cdot \left (1-\dfrac{y(t)}{K} \right) - s \cdot y(t) = y(t) \cdot \left (r - \dfrac{r \cdot y(t)}{K} \right ) - s \cdot y(t)$
$ = y(t) \cdot \left (r - s- \dfrac{r \cdot y(t)}{K} \right ) = (r - s) \cdot y(t) \cdot \left (1  - \dfrac{r \cdot y(t)}{K \cdot (r - s)} \right ); \tag 2$

so if we know how to solve

$ \dfrac {dy}{dt} = r \cdot y(t)\cdot \left (1-\dfrac{y(t)}{K} \right ) \tag 3$

for general $r$ and $K$, replacing $r$ with $r - s$ and $K$ with $K \cdot (r - s) / r$, then in principle we may solve (1) as well.

Answer (score 1):

$$r \cdot y(t)\cdot (1-\frac{y(t)}{K}) - s \cdot y(t) = r \cdot y(t) \cdot (1-\frac{s}{r}-\frac{y(t)}{K})$$

Now, define $1-\frac{s}{r}$ as a new constant $k$, and proceed as before.